# how to change element that fits a component to an element that fits a function in react native

Tags: react-native, tags, react-component

I am a new react native developer, I found a component and I want to use it in a function, but it is not clear to me how I would change it, can I get a help?

Here is the component

```
import TagInput from 'react-native-tag-input';

...

<TagInput
  value={this.state.emails}
  onChange={(emails) => this.setState({ emails })}
  labelExtractor={(email) => email}
  text={this.state.text}
  onChangeText={(text) => this.setState({ text })}
/>
```

I got the code from here https://bestofreactjs.com/repo/jwohlfert23-react-native-tag-input

Comment: Hello! Can you tell us more about what you want to change about the component? Or what you have tried to change, and how it isn't working for you?

Comment: What do you mean by using in a function? Do you want to return this component from a function?

Comment: Please check this to understand what I mean https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/five-ways-to-convert-react-class-components-to-functional-components-with-react-hooks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you are asking how to adapt the code to fit the functional component, which includes converting the `this.setState`.

React provides some thing called React hooks, which you can think of as a way to replace states and lifecycles. You can read more about it here [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html)
In your case, it would go like this:

```
import { useState } from 'react';
...
// useState can only be called inside functional components
const [emails, setEmails] = useState([]);
const [text, setText] = useState('');
...
<TagInput
  value={emails}
  onChange={(emailTags) => setEmails(emailTags)} // to avoid naming confusion
  labelExtractor={(email) => email}
  text={text}
  onChangeText={(inputText) => setText(inputText)}
/>
```

Answer (score 1):

you don't need to convert the component itself, you can use it as it is, but you need to change its implementation.

Basically, if you want to use function components, which is highly recommended now, you need to change the usage of the state in the component which will contain the `<TagInput>`.

Instead of using "this" which points to the class itself, you need to implement a hook called useState.

You can find it the docs here: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html